# Не получается на хостинге beget сделать переход после авторизации на страницу личного кабинета

Tags: php, header, location

```
***<?php
session_start();
require_once 'database.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = md5($password);
    echo $password;
    $link = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($link);
    if (!$result) {
        echo '<p class="error">Неверные пароль или имя пользователя!</p>';
    } else {
        if ($password == $result['password']) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $result['id'];
            echo
            header("Location:http://tocharosta.miksplt4.beget.tech/admin/admin.php");
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error"> Неверные пароль или имя пользователя!</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>***
```

после нажатия на кнопку, пользователь авторизируется, но не происходит автоматический переход на страницу, просто выводит хешированный пароль[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой смысл делать авторизацию вообще, если любой дурак авторизуется через SQL инъекцию вообще без пароля?

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) чётко написано

> **Помните**, функцию header() разрешено вызывать, только **если клиенту ещё не были переданы данные**. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, **перед её вызовом не должно быть HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т. п**. Иногда возникает ошибка, когда при чтении кода файловыми функциями наподобие include или require в коде попадаются пробелы или пустые строки, которые выводятся до вызова функции header(). Те же проблемы могут возникать, когда в одном файле записаны PHP-код и HTML-разметка.

Теперь взгляните на свой код....и задайте себе вопрос: что делает `echo` и как это влияет на `header`?

Так же там есть [примечания](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes) и примеры, что делать, если хочется и заголовки использовать и что-то вывести.

---

А если бы ещё вы [включили отображение ошибок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482), то код бы вам сказал о том, что вы что-то делаете неправильно

Comment: Ну и зачем в сотый раз пережевывать одно и то же?

Comment: Да хз. Мне проще было, чем искать дубликат) Сохраню его в закладки на след. раз))